# iOS equvalent of the Android's Equalizer class

Tags: android, ios, equalizer

I have found the [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) class on Android and I'm wondering if there is similar functionality on iOS7+ or is there any other way to achieve similar effects (audio setup for audio playback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in iOS, Audio Effects, filters, equalizers etc... are implemented as Audio Units. in your case you'll probably want to implement an Audio Unit with component subtype of ***kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ*** . Refer to the Audio Unit component services documentation for further details. you can find further details here: [Audio Unit Component services reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/index.html).

Comment: Is it possible to apply effect on any audio or only on custom audio player?

Comment: if by any audio you mean played back through AVPlayer, then you can use MTAudioProcessingTap to install an AudioUnit into the Audio Pipeline. Basically, AudioUnits are lower level, so if you intend doing anything out of the ordinar, you would probably want access to the raw audiostream. Take a look at this URL https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html. If you need more help, please provide a better idea as to what you're trying to accomplish, I have a mountain of AU code i would be happy to share.

Comment: I'm curious about the equalizer feature (custom) that can be used with ideally any audio source e.g. the built in music player